# One human, two Salesforce user seats - Okta SAML SSO - How to configure?

Tags: saml, okta

In our org, we have some people with two Salesforce user seats, representing different personas and permissions

Example:

- George Washington (the human) - with a single Okta Active Directory entry
- Has SFDC user seats: `george@business-unit1.foo.com` and `george@business-unit2.foo.com`

The org uses Okta as SAML SSO Identity Provider.

We'd like to have two Okta tiles labeled, respectively

- Salesforce Business Unit 1
- Salesforce Business Unit 2

and George clicks on whatever tile he needs to play that persona`

How do we set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some first principles:

- You can't have two Okta applications (the tiles) pointing at the same SFDC Single Signon Configuration

### A Solution

**Business Unit 1**

- Create an Okta application "SFDC Business Unit 1"
- From Okta, you can export the metadata to the SFDC admin
- SFDC admin then creates a new SSO config and imports the metadata.
- SFDC admin then provides back to Okta admin the SFDC login URL
- Set up Federation Ids in the Okta app to match the Federation Id in for `george@business-unit1.foo.com`
- Assign the human (George) to the Okta application "SFDC Business Unit 1". George now sees this Okta tile

**Business Unit 2**

- Create a second Okta application "SFDC Business Unit 2"
- Don't export the metadata; instead, export the cert for this application
- Make a note of the Okta application's External Id
- Go into SFDC and clone the SSO configuration used for Business Unit 1
- Upload the Okta application's cert (the one from the Business Unit 2 app!)
- Paste in the Okta application external Id into the places marked in the screen shot
- SFDC admin then provides back to Okta admin the SFDC login URL
- Set up Federation Ids in the Okta app to match the Federation Id in for `george@business-unit2.foo.com` (that is, each user seat for George has a distinct/different Federation Id)
- Assign the human (George) to the Okta application "SFDC Business Unit 2". George now sees two Okta tiles (apps)

[image]